# Could aspnet_regsql.exe be used to create DB capable of storing several email addresses

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

Q1

A) Is there a way to create membership database ( using aspnet_regsql tool ) where each user could have several email addresses specified ( instead of just one ) during registration process?

B) Is there also a way to somehow "inform" Security wizard in WAT to include new
input fields ( where additional email addresses would be entered ) when creating new user account?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Profiles will solve your problem. Here's a blog post from [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx) on implementing membership with profiles.

Comment: I assume we can't tell aspnet_regsql tool to create additional columns for additional email addresses?